# EF - not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, viewmodel

I am trying to list some food items with a controller. I use Repository pattern with UnitOfWork for the data in another assembly and referenced it in a BaseApiController. The **Data** property is my UnitOfWork instance.

```
var result = Data.Food
            .FindAll()
            .Select(FoodItemViewModel.Create);

return result;
```

and here is my ViewModel:

```
public static Expression<Func<FoodItem, FoodItemViewModel>> Create
    {
        get
        {
            return fi => new FoodItemViewModel
            {
                Id = fi.Id,
                Description = fi.Description,
                DiaryEntries = fi.DiaryEntries
                .Select(s => new DiaryEntityViewModel()
                {
                    Id = s.Id,
                    Quantity = s.Quantity
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

But all I get is:

> "The specified type member 'DiaryEntries' is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation
>   properties are supported."

My DiaryEntries member in the ViewModel is

```
IEnumerable<DiaryEntityViewModel>
```

and my DiaryEntries member in the Data instance is

```
IRepository<DiaryEntry>
```

and DiaryEntry is my model class

and here is my FoodItem model class:

```
public class FoodItem
    {
        private IEnumerable<Measure> measures;
        private IEnumerable<DiaryEntry> diaryEntries;

        public FoodItem()
        {
            this.measures = new HashSet<Measure>();
            this.diaryEntries = new HashSet<DiaryEntry>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual IEnumerable<DiaryEntry> DiaryEntries
        {
            get
            {
                return this.diaryEntries;
            }
            set
            {
                this.diaryEntries = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<Measure> Measures
        {
            get
            {
                return this.measures;
            }
            set
            {
                this.measures = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? I think your issue might be you're passing a function to the DB. Try `.ToList()`ing it before your select statement.

Comment: How is DiaryEntries defined in FoodItem?

Comment: And what is `IRepository<DiaryEntry>`? The message clearly states it should be navigation property.

Comment: Is diary entries a computed property?

Comment: @IvanStoev IRepository<DiaryEntry> is not in his entity, it is inside his UnitOfWork.

Comment: BTW, why are you implementing `UnitOfWork` separately when `DbContext` itself is `UnitOfWork` implementation.

Comment: .ToList()-ing before the Select statement comes to the same error.

Comment: Why is DiaryEntries not auto-implemented?

Comment: sachin - about the auto-implemented properties - this is another topic but even with auto-im. still the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you `FoodItem` class to the one below, **`IEnumerable<T>` is not supported as a type for a navigation collection** :

```
public class FoodItem
{
    public FoodItem()
    {
        this.Measures = new HashSet<Measure>();
        this.DiaryEntries = new HashSet<DiaryEntry>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DiaryEntry> DiaryEntries
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Measure> Measures
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: I made all model classes only with navigational properties but still this awful respond.

Comment: You changed the navigation property type from IEnumerable to ICollection?

Comment: It seems I have to go to sleep or for a new cup of coffee. Stupid mistake. Thanks!